# Problemas al Consumir web service desde PHP

Tags: php

Bueno soy nuevo en esto de los webservices y Tengo un webservice el cual  me brinda la siguiente informacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y utilizo el siguiente código PHP para conectarme y hacer la solicitud de PUT en el webservice.

```html
<?php



$pantalla= "zonas";
$id= "8";

// creo la url + el codigo que modificare

$url= "http://miwebservice.net/api/".$pantalla. "/" . $id ;

//construir el json que debo enviar en el body

    $ConstructorJson = array(
      'ZonaId' => $Datos['txt_codigo'],
      'Nombre' => $Datos['txt_Nombre'],
      'CreadoPor' => $Datos['txt_CreadoPor'],
      'CreadoFecha' => $Datos['txt_CreadoFecha'],
      'ModificadoPor' => $Datos['txt_ModificadoPor'],
      'ModificadoFecha' => $Datos['txt_ModificadoFecha'],
      'Estado' => $Datos['cbo_Estado'],
      'Nota' => $Datos['txt_Notas']
    );
    
$json = json_encode($ConstructorJson);

    $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => $url,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json,
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "Accept: application/json\r\n",
          ),
      ));

      $response = curl_exec($curl);
      $err = curl_error($curl);

      curl_close($curl);

      if ($err) {
         echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
      } else {
         echo $response;
      }    


?>
```

me genera el siguente error

**Length Required
HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.**

alguien me podría ayudar a solucionarlo  y  decirme si el mismo codigo me funcionaria para el metodo POST ?

Comment: Si has escrito en el encabezado de la respuesta esto: `Content-Lenght: lenght` sin indicar exactamente cuál es el tamaño del contenido, te da ese error. Ese tamaño se refiere al tamaño del `<body>` en la respuesta. Lo que te digo está explicado en las [especificaciones de w3.org](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4) Si estás trabajando con algún framework en específico sería bueno que lo indiques para recibir ayuda más precisa.

Comment: Hola Muchas gracias por responder.  No no estoy utilizando ningun tipo Framework

Comment: ¿A qué corresponde pues la segunda imagen, donde aparece algo relativo al `Content-Lenght`?

Comment: ok la segunda imagen es la continuación de la información del webservice . es decir es la misma pagina web (la informacion de como consumirlo)

Comment: mi error realmente es cuando ejecuto el codigo desde un boton me aparece el siguiente texto  ---------- Length Required HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.

Comment: ¿Usas PUT porque quieres guardar algo en el servidor? Si no es así puedes probar con POST. Si debes usar PUT debes revisar la documentación:  http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: es para modificarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno Finalmente resolví el  problema

adjunto el codigo

```html
<?php


function jsonZonaPUT($Datos)
{
//url del webservice + tabla + id del registro a modificar
  $url = "mywebservice.com/zonas/8";

//contruir el arreglo de los datos que enviare 

  $ConstructorJson = array(
      'Nombre' => $Datos['txt_Nombre'],
      'CreadoPor' => $Datos['txt_CreadoPor'],
      'CreadoFecha' => $Datos['txt_CreadoFecha'],
      'ModificadoPor' => $Datos['txt_ModificadoPor'],
      'ModificadoFecha' => $Datos['txt_ModificadoFecha'],
      'Estado' => $Datos['cbo_Estado'],
      'Nota' => $Datos['txt_Notas']
    );
    
// convertir el array a json
  $json = json_encode($ConstructorJson);
  
//crear el arreglo para enviar los datos via Curl
    $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => $url,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json,
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Content-Type: application/json',

          ),
      ));
      
      // si existe algun problema lo imprimira a pantalla sino imprimira el json posteado en webservice
      $response = curl_exec($curl);
      $err = curl_error($curl);

      curl_close($curl);

      if ($err) {
         echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
      } else {
         echo $response;
      }


}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tenes que corregir un par de cosas:

1) Por lo que dice el parámetro ZonaId se pasa en la query de la URL solamente, en el código está también en el body.

2) Si vas a mandar json, tendrias que tener un header de `Content-Type: application/json`

3) Probá con los dos cambios anteriores. Si sigue el error de `content length`, agregá un header más con `Content-Length: 999`. 999 Es la cantidad de bytes que mandas. Tenes que tomar el body ya codificado como json y colocar la longitud del string con `mb_strlen()`.

4) Fijate si tenes problemas con las fechas en el json. Este formato te puede servir de referencia: `2016-08-01T14:25:43.000Z`